# What's the difference between "abbreviation" and "abbreviature"? 

Tags: differences, nouns

What's the difference between these two words, *abbreviation* and *abbreviature*?

Comment: The one you want is "abbreviation".  The other is obsolete/archaic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Abbreviature" appears to have two purposes: an outdated synonym of "abbreviation" and an entirely additional meaning:

> An abridgment; a compendium or abstract.
>
> "This is an excellent abbreviature of the whole duty of a Christian. - Jeremy Taylor"
>
> ([wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abbreviature))

So the current difference is that "abbreviature" applies to large bodies of works or an entire subject; "[abbreviation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abbreviation)" is more applicable to words and phrases.

Answer (score 2):

*Abbreviation* is a common English word which normally means a shortened form of a written word or phrase.

*Abbreviature* is a far rarer word (somewhat technical and/or archaic, in my opinion) that normally means a *condensed* version of something significantly longer than just a word or phrase. An *abstract*, *summary*, or *digest* of an instruction manual, for example.